# Replace the third instance of a period in a character string while keeping the period

Tags: r, date, gsub, substr

I have a character vector with dates, formatted in this way (this is just an example):

`x <- c("03.04.30", "02.06.32", "01.11.33", "10.10.31")`

and so on. I'm using the `as.Date` function as such:

`x <- as.Date(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y")`

and it's working but it's returning years for me in the 2000s, and not in the 1990s as I would like.

My idea is to simply replace the third instance of the period in each element of `x` with `.19` using `gsub` but I cannot come up with a regular expression to do so and I've looked all over the place online and really cannot figure this out.

I've also tried using the `substr` function to replace the 6th character of each element of `x` with `.19` but it's simply replacing the whole character string. Being able to do either of those effectively would help me!

I know I'm probably overlooking a simpler solution but please help me I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
x <- c("03.04.30", "02.06.32", "01.11.33", "10.10.31")
x <- gsub("(\\d{2})$", "19\\1", x)
as.Date(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

To get:

```
[1] "1930-04-03" "1932-06-02" "1933-11-01" "1931-10-10"
```

This assumes the data is consistently formatted otherwise you might want to rethink the regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked for me. I was having trouble with the `replacement` portion of the `sub` function. Just to ensure I'm reading this correctly your `gsub` reads:

Find the group that represents two digits at the end of the string and replace with "19" and then whatever currently exists? I don't quite understand the `\\1` portion of your code. Thanks so much for the help in advance!

Comment: I think you are reading it correctly... `\\1` refers to what was inside `()`. So we are asking `gsub()` to put it back. If you have many `()` then refer to the first with `\\1` second with `\\2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex.

```
x2 <- sub("\\.(\\d{2})$", ".19\\1", x)
x2
#[1] "03.04.1930" "02.06.1932" "01.11.1933" "10.10.1931"

as.Date(x2, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
#[1] "1930-04-03" "1932-06-02" "1933-11-01" "1931-10-10"
```